# Xml file is empty after xml serialization

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I need true output like this `<numbers>12345</numbers>`. But file is empty after serialization. Here is my code:

```
public string Numbers { get; set; }
```

Button click event:

```
private void Ref_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
     Item puz = new Item();
     puz.Numbers = "12345";
     Save(puz);
}
```

Serialize function:

```
public static void Save(Item settings)
{
   using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {
     XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = store.OpenFile(@"data.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
     {
       try
       {
         ser.Serialize(isoStream, settings);
       }
       catch (Exception)
       { }
       isoStream.Close();
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't swallow all exceptions completely silently, you might see an error...

Comment: @mrtig IsolatedStorage does not have a Flush method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx